# FatalThrowableError call to undefined function FirstProject\Http\Controllers\move()

Tags: laravel-5

i m learning a tutorial on fileupload in laravel.
my file is not being uploaded.
there seems to be problem at this code.

```
//move uploaded file
    $destinationPath = 'uploads';
    $file = move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
```

and where exactly i need to create a destination path

These are my full codes

uploadfile.php

```
<body>

<?php 

    echo Form::open(array('url' => '/uploadfile','files' => 'true'));
    echo "Select the file to upload!";
    echo Form::file('image');
    echo Form::submit('Upload File');
    echo Form::close();

 ?>

</body>
```

FileUploadController.php

```
<?php

namespace FirstProject\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('uploadfile');
    }

    public function showUploadFile(Request $req){
        $file = $req->file('image');

        //display the fullname
        echo "File Name: " .$file->getClientOriginalName();
        echo "<br>";

        //display file extension
        echo "File Extension: " .$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        echo "<br>";

        //display file realpath
        echo "File Real Path: " .$file->getRealPath();
        echo "<br>";

        //display file size
        echo "File Size: " .$file->getSize();
        echo "<br>";

        //display file mime type
        echo "File Mime Type: " .$file->getMimeType();

        //move uploaded file
        $destinationPath = 'uploads';
        $file = move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
}
?>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/uploadfile','FileUploadController@index');
Route::post('/uploadfile','FileUploadController@showUploadFile');
```